# Is there any way to see all available keywords in a robotframework library

Tags: python, robotframework

Is there any way to see all available keywords in a robotframework library like dir(package) in python

Comment: "See" in what context? From the command line?

Comment: from command line directly or by running the robot file in command line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Robot Framework's [libdoc](http://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.2/_modules/robot/libdoc.html) module. This is the tool used to generate documentation of Robot Framework keyword libraries. This should generate a HTML document listing all keywords this library exports.

Alternatively, if you're using an IDE that features an auto-complete, you should be able to type the library's name, followed by a dot (example: `MyLibraryName.`) and see all keywords this library exports.

And finally, you could also check out the library's source itself, if you're confident reading Python source code.